# SwiftUI how to use .fixedSize() modifier with TabView to only take up the space it needs?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have a `TabView` that is embeeded in a `ZStack`.  My goal is to make the `ZStack` and it's child `TabView` to only take up the space needed to lay out the views inside the `TabView`.  The `.fixedSize()` modifier accomplishes this if I change my `TabView` to a `VStack` but with a `TabView` it squishes the `TabView` too small.  How can I accomplish my goal while still not obscuring the `TabView`'s content?

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            
            TabView {
                VStack {
                    Text("One")
                    Text("One")
                    Text("One")
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Two")
                    Text("Two")
                    Text("Two")
                }
                VStack {
                    Text("Three")
                    Text("Three")
                    Text("Three")
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            
        }
        
        .fixedSize() //why doesn't this work as expected?
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is that `TabViews`, like `ScrollViews`, `ListViews`, etc., have no intrinsic size. `.fixedSize` reduces a view size to its intrinsic, or natural, size. So, putting `.fixedSize` on them reduces their sizes beyond all recognition. The only thing that would reduce the `TabView` properly would be to put a `.frame()` on it.

Comment: Thanks @Yrb but I don't want to use a hard coded frame height for reasons of different screen sizes and dynamic text sizes, what other options are there for this tabview to only be the size it needs to be?

Comment: While I can understand that you don't want to hard code them, you may be able to come up with some sort of value. I tried a solution with `PreferenceKeys` but it didn't work. I don't think they ever thought a `TabView` would be used like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, for me this did the trick without hardcoding it:

```
TabView(){
....
}
.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Comment: It didnt worked for me

Comment: @MehulThakkar Ham weird, it could be really not working for you or maybe you have different layout or other things affecting your view. Difficult to know with more details.